# sed/awk look for pattern in string and change another pattern on the same line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an F5 bigip.conf text file in which I want to change the route domain from 701 to 703 for all lines showing "10.166.201." The route domain is represented by  %701

```
10.166.201.10%701
10.166.201.15%701
10.166.201.117%701
```

I am able to do this with bash but the problem is that the "else printf" command (I've also tried echo), which is supposed to print out all other lines, incorrectly parses things like "\r\n" and leaves them as "rn"

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
if [[ $line = *"10.166.201"* ]]; 
    then
printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -e 's/701/703/'

else printf '%s\n' "$line"  

fi  

done < bigip.conf > bigip.conf_updated
```

Is there a way to stop printf and echo from modifying the "\r\n"?

Is there a better way to do this in sed/awk?

Thanks.

Comment: oh man, you have `\r` too in your Input_file, if you want to remove them then I added that solution too in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regexp address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses):

```
sed '/10\.166\.201\./s/%701/%703/' bigip.conf
```

---

Once you made sure that the command works for you, you can change the file in place using `-i`:

```
sed -i'' '/10\.166\.201\./s/%701/%703/' bigip.conf
```

With GNU sed you can omit the option value for `-i`:

```
sed -i '/10\.166\.201\./s/%701/%703/' bigip.conf
```

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to put that in a script for another IP search and route domains change, could I use sed -i '/10\.166\.201\./s/701/703/'  - i '/10\.165\.202\./s/702/704/'  ?

Comment: Almost. it should be `sed -i -e '/10\.166\.201\./s/701/703/' -e '/10\.165\.202\./s/702/704/'`

Comment: Consider what that would do if the input was `10.166.201.701%35` or `110.166.201.10%701`.

Comment: Is that `10.166.203.189`? :)

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, I was thinking about that, but since 701 is > 255 it should be fine. But you are right, when the input 701 changes to, let's say 123, then it would be indeed a problem. I changed the command to `s/%701/%703/`

Comment: You should also anchor it (`/^10\....$`) No-one said there can't be invalid values in the file, just that they want to update some specific valid values :-). That's the problem with sample input that only contains the target values out of context - we have no idea what the rest of the file might contain!

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} /your_string/{sub(/701/,"703")} 1'   Input_file
```

Also in case you want to save output into same Input_file itself then do following:

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} /your_string/{sub(/701/,"703")} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** In case your Input_file has `\r` in them then I added `{gsub(/\r/,"")}` in my above codes, in case you don't have them you could remove them from codes.

***EDIT2:*** Changing string to your_string also change `.` to `\.` too in your address.

Answer (score 1):

`sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(10\.166\.201\.[[:digit:]]+%70)1/\13/'
```

- The captured group, `(10\.166\.201\.[[:digit:]]+%70)` matches `10.166.201.` literally, then one or more digits, then `%70` literally
- Outside the captured group, `1` matches literally; in the replacement, the the captured group is used and 1 is replaced by 3

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
10.166.201.10%701
10.166.201.15%701
10.166.201.117%701

% sed -E 's/(10\.166\.201\.[[:digit:]]+%70)1/\13/' file.txt
10.166.201.10%703
10.166.201.15%703
10.166.201.117%703
```

Answer (score 1):

The clear, simple, robust, efficient way is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"; FS=OFS="%"} index($1,"10.166.201.")==1{ $2="703" } 1' file
```

Note that you don't need to escape the `.`s or anchor to avoid partial matches because the above simply treats the IP address as a string appearing at the start of the line. The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS to preserve your `\r\n` line endings.